# NavigationController Push is not working ios 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Hello I have navigation stack(Flow) and top visible view controller is **M**

1. I am creating one more new navigation controller **N** with view controller **A**.
2. Now Presenting **N** on **M**
3. Pushing view controller **B** in **A** (self.navigationcontroller)

Push is not working and and getting error **while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated** in iOS 11 only.
Thanks,

Comment: Share code or Storybord image

Comment: Not using story board. Implemented  through xib and programmatically.

Comment: ok share code of  Now Presenting N on M and  Pushing view controller B in A (self.navigationcontroller)  code of step 2 and 3

Comment: try `push` in `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`

Comment: This type of error comes when you try to push second view controller in the viewDidLoad of the first viewcontroller. Since one transition is already happening. Your code may help understand the problem better. Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned should not create an issue. But below mentioned would not throw for sure what you have mentioned.

Add push B into N code in the modal presentation's completion block

```
present(N, animated: true) { [weak self]
    N.pushViewController(B, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly following navigation structure.

From view controller **M** you need to present navigation controller **N** like this:

```
self.navigationController?.present(navN, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here self is view controller **M** and **navN** is new navigation controller.

By doing this it will open view controller A from here you need to push to view controller B:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VCb, animated: true)
```

Self is view controller **A** and **VCb** is new view controller B.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3/Swift 4**

first of all you need to set navigation controller on which you want to present.After that do navigation process on your second view controller.

- **Example like that**

  ```
     let firstPresentVC = FirstVC(nibName:"FirstVC",bundle:nil)
     let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController:firstPresentVC)
     navVC.isNavigationBarHidden = true
     self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion:nil)
  ```

**Now You are on Present Stack With Navigation**

You can push after that

```
let secondPushVC = secondPushVC(nibName:"secondPushVC",bundle:nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondPushVC, animated: true)
```